# Sorting a table with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, custom-controls

Alright, I'm ready to take the PHP plunge. I've got an HTML5 animation with table sorting tools (a button for "by date," another for "by title"), and I wanted to have these sort a table on the same page. I've Googled around and haven't found any suitably customizable ready-made table sorters, so I've learned some PHP basics as well as a bit of jQuery, and wanted to do this. 
The HTML5 animation was compiled in Hype, and is technically an HTML document referring to a .js file. 
If this is possible, any help is appreciated.

EDIT
Alright, I've got some code for you. There's more than a bit of it, so brace yourselves. This first one is from the "Hype.js" file, which is the file in question. Once again, this was completely compiled by Hype.

(dead link removed)

Now here's headeranimated_hype_generated_script.js. The second part of the link (starting with http://) is a link to the page I intend to put the table on, but since I've got less than 10 reputation, I'm limited to 2 links.

(dead links removed)

(I figure it's easier to view them in-browser as a standalone page rather than a comment box here)

My concrete question is, is it possible to use PHP or possible jQuery to use custom buttons to sort a table?

Comment: Do you want to sort the table BEFORE the page loads or AFTER the page loads?

Comment: Is this paginated (eg: are your records split across many pages)? Do you want to sort them on the server side (before the page loads, PHP) or the client side (after the page is loaded, JS)?

Comment: showing us the code would be helpful

Comment: give me code or give me death

Comment: If you expect someone to read all that code, offer to pay him. Seriously. (Besides: what is your *concrete* question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JQuery Table Sorter Plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo).

Comment: That looks good, but is it possible to use it with custom buttons? All I see is that it has two themes (blue and green).